# Java regular expression for UserName with length range

Tags: java, regex, validation

I am writing a regular expression to validate UserName.

**Here is the rule:**

- Length: 6 - 20 characters
- Must start with letter a-zA-Z
- Can contains a-zA-Z0-9 and dot(.)
- Can't have 2 consecutive dots

Here is what I tried:

```
public class TestUserName {

    private static String USERNAME_PATTERN = "[a-z](\\.?[a-z\\d]+)+";
    private static Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(USERNAME_PATTERN, CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(pattern.matcher("user.name").matches()); // true
        System.out.println(pattern.matcher("user.name2").matches()); // true
        System.out.println(pattern.matcher("user2.name").matches()); // true

        System.out.println(pattern.matcher("user..name").matches()); // false
        System.out.println(pattern.matcher("1user.name").matches()); // false
    }
}
```

The pattern I used is good but no length constraint.

I tried to append {6,20} constraint to the pattern but It failed.

```
"[a-z](\\.?[a-z\\d]+)+{6,20}" // failed pattern to validate length
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: you cannot append `{6,20}` anywhere

Comment: The range-definition should not follow but be used instead of the plus ('+') : `[a-z](\\.?[a-z\\d]+){6,20}`

Comment: The `{6,20}` after the `+` is what the validator is balking about. But removing it will not fix it! It will allow repeating the `(..+)` part, which can be as long as you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a lookahead regex for all the checks:

```
^[a-zA-Z](?!.*\.\.)[a-zA-Z.\d]{5,19}$
```

- Using `[a-zA-Z.\d]{5,19}` because we have already matched one char `[a-zA-Z]` at start this making total length in the range `{6,20}`
- Negative lookahead `(?!.*\.\.)` will assert failure if there are 2 consecutive dots

Equivalent Java pattern will be:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z](?!.*\\.\\.)[a-zA-Z.\\d]{5,19}$");
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a negative look ahead to prevent double dots:

```
"^(?!.*\\.\\.)(?i)[a-z][a-z\\d.]{5,19}$"
```

- `(?i)` means case insensitve (so `[a-z]` means `[a-zA-Z]`)
- `(?!.*\\.\\.)` means there isn't two consecutive dots anywhere in it

The rest is obvious.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/R9Cx4vplsa).

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following regex :

```
^(?=.{6,20}$)(?!.*\.\.)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.]+$
```

The `(?=.{6,20}$)` positive lookahead makes sure the text will contain 6 to 20 characters, while the `(?!.*\.\.)` negative lookahead makes sure the text will not contain `..` at any point.

Answer (score 1):

This will also suffice (for only matching)

```
(?=^.{6,20}$)(?=^[A-Za-z])(?!.*\.\.)
```

For capturing, the matched pattern, you can use

```
(?=^.{6,20}$)(?=^[A-Za-z])(?!.*\.\.)(^.*$)
```

Comment: It doesn't check for the third part of the rule : characters others than `[a-zA-Z0-9.]` will be matched

Comment: @Aaron It says `Can contain a-zA-Z0-9 and dot(.)` and not specifically that `it should` only contain  these..i assumed it that way